# Selected JSON data to c# object

Tags: c#, json, .net

```json
{
    "name": "India",
    "topLevelDomain": [".in"],
    "alpha2Code": "IN",
    "alpha3Code": "IND",
    "callingCodes": ["91"],
    "capital": "New Delhi",
    "altSpellings": ["IN", "Bhārat", "Republic of India", "Bharat Ganrajya"],
    "subregion": "Southern Asia",
    "region": "Asia",
    "population": 1380004385,
    "latlng": [20.0, 77.0],
    "demonym": "Indian",
    "area": 3287590.0,
    "gini": 35.7,
    "timezones": ["UTC+05:30"],
    "borders": ["AFG", "BGD", "BTN", "MMR", "CHN", "NPL", "PAK", "LKA"],
    "nativeName": "भारत",
    "numericCode": "356",
    "flags": {
      "svg": "https://flagcdn.com/in.svg",
      "png": "https://flagcdn.com/w320/in.png"
    },
    "currencies": [{ "code": "INR", "name": "Indian rupee", "symbol": "₹" }],
    "languages": [
      {
        "iso639_1": "hi",
        "iso639_2": "hin",
        "name": "Hindi",
        "nativeName": "हिन्दी"
      },
      {
        "iso639_1": "en",
        "iso639_2": "eng",
        "name": "English",
        "nativeName": "English"
      }
    ],
    "translations": {
      "br": "Índia",
      "pt": "Índia",
      "nl": "India",
      "hr": "Indija",
      "fa": "هند",
      "de": "Indien",
      "es": "India",
      "fr": "Inde",
      "ja": "インド",
      "it": "India",
      "hu": "India"
    },
    "flag": "https://flagcdn.com/in.svg",
    "regionalBlocs": [
      {
        "acronym": "SAARC",
        "name": "South Asian Association for Regional Cooperation"
      }
    ],
    "cioc": "IND",
    "independent": true
  }
```

This is my JSON data.From this I need to convert

- name
- population
- area
- altSpellings

these values to c#

Answer (score 0):

Using the `Newtonsoft.Json` library you can load the JSON content into a `JObject` and treat it like a dictionary where the property names are the key values like so:

```
//Load the JSON into a JObject
var json = ...
var jsonObject = JObject.Parse(json);

//Pull out the property values using the name as a key
var name = jsonObject["name"].ToString();
var population = int.Parse(jsonObject["population"].ToString());
var area = jsonObject["area"].ToString();
var altSpellings = new List<string>();

foreach (var altSpelling in (JArray)jsonObject["altSpellings"])
    altSpellings.Add(altSpelling.ToString());
```

This is a quick way to get the values out without having to create concrete types to deserialise into. If you happen to have a class that maps onto this JSON structure ([json2csharp](https://json2csharp.com/) can be handy here) then you could instead use `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>` instead to deserialise into an instance of that type where you can access the fields directly.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a class with the properties you need

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

Data data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Data>(json);

string name = data.Name; // India
```

result

```
{
  "name": "India",
  "population": 1380004385,
  "area": 3287590,
  "altSpellings": [
    "IN",
    "Bhārat",
    "Republic of India",
    "Bharat Ganrajya"
  ]
}
```

class

```
public partial class Data
{
    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("population")]
    public long Population { get; set; }
    
    [JsonProperty("area")]
    public long Area { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("altSpellings")]
    public List<string> AltSpellings { get; set; }

}
```